# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

Using the following Python 3.10 project with a dir structure similar to that shown below

```py
├── source
│   ├── helper
|   └──── EvalHelper.py
|
└── main.py
```

I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'` when trying to run the `main.py`.

```py
# main.py
from source.helper.EvalHelper import EvalHelper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eval_helper = EvalHelper()
    eval_helper.perform_eval()
```

I've already tried to include the project's dir into the `PYTHONPATH` and the following `sys.path` approach:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
```

It's expected to import the EvalHelper (`from source.helper.EvalHelper import EvalHelper`) without any problem.

The `main.py` is automatically called by AWS Sagemaker through `/usr/local/bin/python main.py`. The project is inside the folder `/opt/ml/code/`, which is included in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: How are you running `main.py`? From which directory?

Comment: Is `EvalHelper.py` inside the helper folder?

Comment: It is automatically started from AWS Sagemaker through: `/usr/local/bin/python main.py`

Comment: you dont have any `__init__.py` files

Comment: Hello @Sayse, I thought the `__init__.py` was not required after Python 3.4. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is adding "lib" to `sys.path` supposed to help if there is no directory called "lib"?

Comment: To do what you want, "EvalHelper.py" would have to be inside the "helper" directory.  That's not what your tree shows.  It shows it as a peer of "helper".  `__init__.py` is no longer required AS LONG AS it's only a namespace directory, and does not contain any Python files.

Comment: Hello @mkrieger1, should I change `lib` to `source`? If so, I just tested it, and it didn't work.

Comment: You are right @TimRoberts. I've fixed the directory tree.

Comment: Yes, obviously, if you want to add "source" to `sys.path`, you should change `sys.path.append(... "lib")` to `sys.path.append(... "source")`. If it doesn't work you have another problem.